# I coded to fetch the PROGRAM PATH in chromium

Tags: android, chromium

I coded to fetch the **PROGRAM PATH** in *chromium android* but the path is like this - **ProgramPath":"/data/app/org.chromium.chrome-1/base.apk** so can i change the name of **base.apk** to **chrome.apk** or **it can't be changed** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android supports Split APK so in **ProgramPath** the base.apk is native process and it can't be changed, unless we hard code the ProgramPath to something else.